# RXJS Observable, with a dynamic function pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to return an observable with a pipe that gets populated every time it gets called.
To demonstrate what exactly this means, look at the example below:

```
const myObservable = timer(1000);
return myObservable.pipe(getCustomPipe());
```

```
function getCustomPipe() {
   return condition ? pipe(1,2,3) : pipe(4,5,6)
}
```

What actually happens in my current approach, `getCustomPipe()` is called once and the result kept into the observable pipe without calling it again, and this is expected as I'm calling the function inside the pipe without introducing some kind of pipe factory function.

How it should be: (`getCustomPipe` is called everytime the observable is called)

```
return myObservable.pipe(
    mergePipe(() => getCustomPipe())
);

// mergePipe is an imaginary pipe factory
```

`getCustomPipe` is called every time the observable is called; in this case, every `1000ms`, a new pipe is used for the observable based on the condition.

Is there any solution for this kind of pipe problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "*is called everytime the observable is called*"? You want the function to run when subscribe happens or each time observable emits a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve that with `map()` and `switchAll()`. The idea is to have some kind of factory that calls `getCustomPipe()` every time a new value is emitted.

I did it making `map()` a factory:

```js
function getCustomPipe() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5            // randomly switch between two operators
    ? map((x: number) => {              // one of them multiplies
        console.log("multiply", x);
        return x * x;
      })
    : map((x: number) => {              // the other one adds
        console.log("add", x);
        return x + x;
      });
}

const myObservable = interval(1000);    // simulate emitting a value every second
const obs = myObservable.pipe(
  map((v) => getCustomPipe()(of(v))),   // `map()` calls its callback every time so the condition above gets called as well dynamically changing the operator
  switchAll()                           // the Observable created in the previous operator gets switched and produces a value
);

obs.subscribe(console.log);
```

The output of the above code will be similar to this one:

```
multiply 0
0
add 1
2
add 2
4
multiply 3
9
add 4
8
multiply 5
25
add 6
12
add 7
14
```

Which I believe is your desired behavior - use a different pipe operator every time a value is emitted.

Here is a working example: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-proskuriakova-jrfgyp?file=/src/index.ts:111-505)